# Installing Pandas on MacOS

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am using MacOS Big Sur version 11.2.3.

I installed pyenv using brew, and then used pyenv to install python 3.9.4 and set it as global. I also used pip to install Jupyter

I then installed pandas using

`pip install pandas`

I got the following output:

---------------begin output----------------

Requirement already satisfied: pandas in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (1.2.4)

Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.7.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (2.8.1)

Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.16.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (1.20.2)

Requirement already satisfied: pytz>=2017.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from pandas) (2021.1)

Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages (from python-dateutil>=2.7.3->pandas) (1.15.0)

------------------end output---------------------

However, when I run a Jupyter Notebook and import numpy and pandas, I am able to import numpy but not pandas:

```
import numpy as np

import pandas as pd

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-59ab05e21164> in <module>
      1 import numpy as np
----> 2 import pandas as pd

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

What am I doing wrong? I suspect that numpy is picking up some old installation of numpy, and the new installations I did are not getting picked up. Is there some PATH or environment variable I need to set?

Comment: Pyenv's Python interpreters are generally installed under `~/.pyenv`. The `/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages` messages imply that the packages are installed in another (system or `brew` installed) Python interpreter's site packages directory. What if you explicitly do `~/.pyenv/versions/3.9.4/bin/python -m pip install jupyter pandas`?

Comment: Okay!! I got this fixed. I did something brute force though. First I used brew to uninstall python as well as jupyter. Then used pip to uninstall pandas. Finally I installed everything once again. It works now! Thanks for the help!